# is_directory () in VS2012 returning false for even directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++-tr2

I am running through a directory containing multiple sub-directories. I am using     recursive_directory_iterator. I have directory asr->collections->(multiple directories and couple of text files)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std::tr2::sys;

int main () {
std::string path_;
std::cout << " Enter the path ";
std::cin >> path_;

auto dir_path = path(path_);

for (auto it = directory_iterator(dir_path); it != directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
    const auto& file = it->path();
    std::cout << " path : " << file << std::endl;

    if (is_directory (status(it->path()))) 
        std::cout << " It is a directory. " << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << " It is not a directory. " << std::endl;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

I know I had posted this earlier. It was a silly mistake, I changed it. But it is still bugy. The issue I am having is the is-directory returns false for everything. 
Am I using it wrong. I have linked the MSDN URL below.

I installed boost and ran the code. It worked !
Boost Source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\filesystem.hpp>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main () {
std::string path_;
std::cout << " Enter the path ";
std::cin >> path_;

auto dir_path = path(path_);

for (auto it = directory_iterator(dir_path); it != directory_iterator(); ++it)
{
    const auto& file = it->path();
    std::cout << " path : " << file << std::endl;

    if (is_directory (status(it->path()))) 
        std::cout << " It is a directory. " << std::endl;
    else 
        std::cout << " It is not a directory. " << std::endl;
}
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874754.aspx

Also, can I use the boost filesystem documentation be used as a tutorial for this, since there is no good documentation as to what is what and how to use it.

Comment: The Boost documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm) is applicable to VC++ 2012 and 2013; the Boost documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) is applicable to VC++ 2015. (Note that these are different versions of Boost.Filesystem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was fixed after I updated the Visual Studio with first major update.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (is_directory (status(dir_path)) )
```

Yes, you are using it wrong.  Try testing the file, not dir_path.  You already know that dir_path is a directory.

Comment: I changed it to if(is_directory(status(file)). I also added else block calling it is not a directory. Now only that else block gets called.

Comment: I tried it by using boost. It worked. But it doesn't work with microsofts implementation.